# difference between echo and println in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

While writing pipelines in Jenkins using Groovy, we can interchangeably use `echo` and `println` statements. Is there any difference between these statements?

For example,

```
buildNumber = "1.10";
echo "BUILD #${buildNumber}";
println "BUILD #${buildNumber}";
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a slight difference, as echo is a step where println is groovy.  The echo step may actually make a step reference on the output view of Jenkins step view and blue ocean steps.  The println may just output a log without creating those extra visual step references in the UI.